# Get element's updated offset after panel is expanded

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an anchor link that points to a field that is inside a collapsible panel (it could be inside a panel that is inside a panel). I have code that when the user clicks on the anchor link, all the parent panels will open if it's hidden and scroll to the field by using jQuery `offset().top`. However, the value from `offset()` is not updated after the panel is open. Some sample code:

```
$anchor.click(function() {
  $.each($panels, function(key, panel) {
    if (\\ panel is closed) {
      $(panel).collapse('show');
    }
  })
  $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top}, 'slow');
});
```

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Was this section a mistake? Or did you take out the logic?

```
if (\\ panel is closed)
```

Also, I think you should be using this.href to access the link target instead of this.hash? 
Are you able to post the 'a' element's code?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10840257/jquery-get-hash-of-a-element-using-on-event) seems to be similar.

Comment: I omitted the condition. It is just a normal `a` element though... I don't think that is the problem. The problem is when I get the field's offset, it's always the old offset and not the updated one after the panel is expanded.